# restrict scrolling on footer

Tags: html, css

I have a Html page with a menu bar created in the footer . Presently , the whole page is scrollable. How do restrict the scrolling for the footer. SO, i am looking for scrolling only on content of page .

code for the footer menu bar is as follows:

```
#menu-bar {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 10px;
    background: #F07C1F;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: The code is right. What is the issue you are facing? Can we see the HTML of the footer?

Comment: With fixed positioning the footer shouldn't scroll with the rest of the page. Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where you demonstrate what isn't working?

Comment: Seems to work for me - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fuQm/)

Comment: Your code is correct, what problem your facing? If you know only tamil you can talk with chat i granted you to access http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19992/tamil-front-end-developers

Comment: The menu bar behaviour is correct however the rest of the content on the page is scrolling beneath it and i would like the scrolling to stop above the menubar/footer.

Comment: @Swetha Put padding at the bottom of the body equal to the height of the footer. That way content will not flow behind the footer.

Answer (score 1):

positioned elements, is what you are looking for...

http://jsfiddle.net/7fuQm/1/

```
#menu-bar {
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 10px;
    background: #F07C1F;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#body {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:50px;    
    left: 0px;   
    overflow:auto;
}
p
{
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This works with normal content . But we have floating div's that do not stay within this container.

Comment: you won't be able to remove the end scrolling if you can't contain those elements within a container.